# shortcut to recursively copying a directory preserving modes, ownerships and hard and symbolic links

Tags: symbolic-link, hardlink, cp

I am using the following to recursively copy a directory while preserving modes, permissions as well as hard and symbolic links:

```
cp -pr --preserve=links dir-a dir-b
```

However I have the following problems with the above:

1. the man page for **cp** is not explicit on what happens if both *-p*
   and *--preserve* are specified. In my bash the effect of both is applied but I don't
   know how portable this is.
2. the man page for **cp** is not clear on
   what "links" means when given as an argument to *--preserve*. Hard, symbolic or both? In my bash it's *both*
   which is what I want, but again it is not explicitly stated
3. The command is long and not easily typed and I don't want to add too many aliases.

Are there any other idioms that you use for the above?